# Mod_Rewrite in htaccess for Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The URL structure for Joomla 1.5 changed in version 2.5.

Before it was:

```
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=587&Itemid=73
```

Now it's:

```
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=587&Itemid=114
```

*Note the `id` and `Itemid` numbers change based on page and while all pages have an `id` not all have the `Itemid` in the URL.

While we updated all links in the database lots of people still have the old link structure so we want to edit the `.htaccess` file so if someone enters the old structure it will forward to the right structure.

Simply put any URL entered at `example.com` with `task=view` in the URL should be replaced with `view=article`.

Does anyone know a simple way to do this in `.htaccess`?

Comment: Does the example case you've given cover the structure of the request for all of the redirecting you're looking to do?

Comment: Actually just found the solution: http://www.codejoomla.com/joomla-user-guide/old-urls-dont-work-after-upgrading-10-to-17.html unless someone knows a better way.

Comment: That should do the trick!  Post it as an answer when the system lets you and mark it as accepted, so the next person who runs into this will find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found here: http://www.codejoomla.com/joomla-user-guide/old-urls-dont-work-after-upgrading-10-to-17.html

```
update `jos_content`
set `introtext` = replace(introtext,'task=view','view=article');

update `jos_content`
set `introtext` = replace(introtext,'task=category','view=category');

update `jos_content`
set `introtext` = replace(introtext,'task=blogcategory','view=category&layout=blog');

update `jos_content`
set `introtext` = replace(introtext,'option=com_wrapper&Itemid=','option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=');</pre>
```

Comment: Not quite sure how this would solve your initial problem stated in the question... of redirecting old links to new (for the benefit of SEO / backlinks)? Doesn't this update any old internal links that are stored in the database (which I thought had already been done, according to the question)?

Answer (score 0):

To replace `task=view` in the query string with `view=article` using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`, you could do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|.*&)task=view(&.*|$)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /$0?%1view=article%2 [R=301,L]
```

We capture the text (if any) before and after the snippet we want to remove. These are then referenced using the `%1` and `%2` backreferences in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string.

The `$0` backreference simply contains the matched URL-path (ie. `index.php`).